# How to bind slides to a button to call them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been seeing some premade slider that have the functionality to call them using a button aside from sliding using directional arrows/button. Currently in the process of trying to finish my slider. So far I've managed to make it slide left and right. Right now I'm planning to create a controls to manual the slides. Lets say if click on slide 4 button it will show slide button.

My dilemma right now is that i'm not sure if I can add the controls on my current build since I created the slider using `if/else`. I was thinking if I should recreate it and build it using javascript arrays. I can't seem to find a tutorial on how to build it.

Here is a preview of my current build

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function timelineSlider() {

  var position         = 0,
      sliderContainer  = $('.slider-container').width(),
      slider           = $('.slider-container .slider'),
      sliderItems      = $('.slider li'),
      totalSlides      = $('.slider li').length;

  slider.width(sliderContainer*totalSlides);
  sliderItems.outerWidth(sliderContainer);

     //next slide    
     $('.next').click(function(){
         slideRight();
     });

     //previous slide
     $('.prev').click(function(){
         slideLeft();
     });


     function slideLeft(){
         position --;
         if ( position == -1 ) { position = totalSlides-1; }
         slider.css('left', - (sliderContainer*position));  
         console.log(position);
     }


     function slideRight(){
         position ++;
         if( position == totalSlides ) { position = 0; }
         slider.css('left', - (sliderContainer*position )); 
     }
    }

    timelineSlider();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        timelineSlider();
    })
    

    
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.slider-container {
  width: 1160px;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .slider-container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .slider-container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%; } }
  .slider-container .slider {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; }
    .slider-container .slider li {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 40px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="slider-container">
     <ul class="slider">
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
         <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
         <li>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </li>
         <li>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </li>
         <li>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
         </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="prev">
     prev
     </div>
     
     <div class="next">
     next
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add index to each silde and create function to navigate by number

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking if I should just `.index` to build the controls. Still wondering how to build it

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code but this is not final code:

```js
var x;
timelineSlider = function() {

  var position = 0,
    sliderContainer = $('.slider-container').width(),
    slider = $('.slider-container .slider'),
    sliderItems = $('.slider li'),
    totalSlides = $('.slider li').length;

  slider.width(sliderContainer * totalSlides);
  sliderItems.outerWidth(sliderContainer);

  //next slide    
  $('.next').click(function() {
    slideRight();
  });

  //previous slide
  $('.prev').click(function() {
    slideLeft();
  });


  function slideLeft() {
    position--;
    if (position == -1) {
      position = totalSlides - 1;
      current = totalSlides - 1;
    }
    slider.css('left', -(sliderContainer * position));
    current--;
    $('#res').html(current);
    console.log(position);
  }


  function slideRight() {
    position++;
    if (position == totalSlides) {
      position = 0;
      current = 0;
    }
    current++;
    $('#res').html(current);
    slider.css('left', -(sliderContainer * position));
  }
  var current = 1;
  this.moveTo = function(index) {
    if (current > index) {
      for (var i = current; i > index; i--) {
        slideLeft();
      }
    } else if (current < index) {
      for (var i = current; i < index; i++) {
        slideRight();
      }
    }
  }
}
$('#goto2').click(function() {
  x.moveTo(2);
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  x = new timelineSlider();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    timelineSlider();
  })



});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
            */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 1160px;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .slider-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.slider-container .slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.slider-container .slider li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider-container">
    <ul class="slider">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>
        4
      </li>
      <li>
        5
      </li>
      <li>
        6
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="prev">
      prev
    </div>

    <div class="next">
      next
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="goto2">Go to 2</button>
<div id="res"></div>
```